# Getting runtime error 1004 method paste of object _worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

Getting runtime error 1004 method paste of object _worksheet failed for below code
Please help, thanks in Advance.

```
Sub Move()
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
        erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        Sheet1.Paste Destination = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Copy
        Sheet1.Paste Destination = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 2)

        Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
        Sheet1.Paste Destination = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 3)
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit`
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You should check how to reference the `Workbook` and `Worksheet` objects. This is wrong: `Sheet1.Cells` unless you define `Set Sheet1 = Workbooks(thisbook).Worksheets(desiredworksheet)`

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos that is not entirely correct.  `Sheet1` could be the code name of the sheet, if so the use is correct.

Comment: I took that into account, however I highly doubt that was the case

Answer (score 0):

Move some thing around and do the whole in one line:

```
Sub Move()
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1),Sheet1.Cells(lastrow , 3)).Copy Sheet2.Cells(erow, 1)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheet2.Columns().AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

now if that does not work the perhaps the code names are incorrect and one should replace all the `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` with `Worksheets("Sheet1")` and `Worksheets("Sheet2")` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

along the lines of @ScottCraner 's solution, you could manage sheet references with the use of `With ...End With` block and avoid multiple repetitions:

```
Sub Move()    
    With Sheet1 ' reference Sheet1 once and for all...
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3).Copy Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) ' all Range objects beginning with dots are referencing the object after `With` keyword (i.e. Sheet1)
    End With
    Sheet2.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

BTW, using `Destination` parameter of `Copy` method you don't "activate" `CutCopyMode`, hence no need to set it to `False`

---

and should you be interested in copying/pasting values only, then nest another `With ...End With` block to reference the "source" range:

```
Sub Move()    
    With Sheet1 ' reference Sheet1 once and for all...
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 3) ' reference Sheet1 columns A:C range from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
            Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value ' get Sheet2 range as its column A last not empty cell, resize it as last referenced range and fill it with its values
        End With
    End With
    Sheet2.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```